# Powering a motor using a microbit

Tags: motor, relay

I have a microbit setup with a relay controlled by pin 0. The relay is being used to turn on a simple motor. Everything works fine when the motor is connected to a separate 3v power source, but if I try use the gnd and 3v outputs of the microbit to power the motor the microbit immediately resets once the relay switches on.

These are my connections to the relay:
Microbit 3v > relay DC+
Microbit gnd > relay DC- 
Microbit p0 > relay IN

This fails:
Microbit 3v > relay NC > relay com > motor > microbit gnd

This works:
 3v battery + > relay NC > relay com > motor >  3v battery -

I have tried adding a resistor in the path, but the smallest I have is 170 ohm which is too much to power the motor.

Comment: Don't use a series resistor. Use a circuit like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95140/purpose-of-the-diode-and-capacitor-in-this-motor-circuit -- or if you want to be able to drive the motor forwards and backwards, use an H-bridge: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80137/how-diodes-protect-h-bridge-dc-motor-driver

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some decoupling.

Comment: @briandrummond - do you mean using a capacitor to separate the power from the ?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor ? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might be trying to draw too much current through the Micro:bit itself (through its 3V Pin). You could try using the same powersource wired to both Micro:Bit AND the motor (in parallel) - with the relay on the positive motor wire.

Comment: Indeed, routing either power or ground to a motor through an MCU board is fundamentally the wrong idea.